# How Firebase Dynamic Links deciedes to return social metadata instead redirections flow

Tags: firebase, bots, user-agent, firebase-dynamic-links

When creating a Firebase Dynamic Link, metadata information for social can be provided (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews). This metadata information appears properly when the dynamic link is shared on most of the social platforms (e.g. facebook, twitter etc.) But metadata doesn't appear in some apps/platforms, including our own app.

It seems firebase is using User-Agent string to determine if the request for the dynamic link is being originated from a social platform bot.

So my question is how can I make sure that my request for metadata is identified correctly and metadata is returned by Firebase. Is there anything I can put in the User-Agent or any other HTTP header to indicate that request is for the metadata?

I know the simplest solution will be to use same Use-Agent value as some other well known social media bot, but it seems wrong and dishonest.